# jquery pop up is not working in ios phone devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have problem with the some jquery events which are not working in ios phone devices but working fine in all desktops and android devices.
I have added jquery popup library for popup which is on this link : http://www.sapphireseas.com/scripts/jquery.fullscreen-popup.js
Here is the code which i am using to initialize the popup.

```
$(function() {
              $(".open-popup").fullScreenPopup({
                  bgColor: '#171946'
              });
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of your page so we can see where you loaded the resources? (It may be the problem)
Have you tried to initialize the popup on $(window).on('load'.......

Comment: Here is the link : http://www.sapphireseas.com/charter-yacht-moka.html
it is working on all window desktops ,  mac desktops and in android devices, Just the issues on I-phone and I-pad devices.